# Matlab: merging a new script with inbuilt code to compare the execution time

Tags: matlab, matrix, time, concurrency

Please, I have this code for determinant that runs but does not display the output only the time it does display. Can gurus in the house help me out.

```
function determ=calll(A)
A=input('rand()');
[rows, columns] = size(A);
tic;
if rows==2:size(A);
    for m11=A(2:end,2:end);
        m1n=A(2:end,1:end-1);
        mn1=A(1:end-1,2:end);
        mnn=A(1:end-1,1:end-1);
        m11nn=A(1:end-2,1:end-2);
        deter=(m11)*(mnn)-((m1n)*(mn1));
        determ=deter./deternew(m11nn);
    end
end
toc
disp('determinant =')
```

The real issue is that

1. I want to incorporate random matrix in the code so that when I run it, a random matrix will be used only just for me to specify the order of the matrix because I can not input 1000 by 1000 matrix manually.
2. An inbuilt Matlab code for determinant should also be embedded in my script.
3. Time of execution should be included for my code and for the inbuilt Matlab code.
4. In all, when I run the program, it should ask for the order (since a random matrix must be used) and compute the determinant using this code and the inbuilt Matlab code concurrently. Note that the determinant of this code and Matlab will be the same but their time of execution will be different. So my output after execution should be in two forms

   - the value of the determinant of my script and the time taken for the execution
   - the value of the determinant of the inbuilt Matlab method and the time taken for the execution.

@EBH

```
function out = thanksEBH
A = input('matrix A =');
[rows, columns] = size(A);
N=100;
t = zeros(N,1);
for k = 1:N
end
tic;
out=1;
for i = 1:rows
    out = prod(A(i,i)*A(i,end));
end
t(k,1) = toc;
for i = 1:rows
    out = prod(A(i,end-1)*A(end,i));
end
t(k,2) = toc;
t(k) = toc;
```

Comment: read carefully the answer below. You say you know all that, and you need to create a random matrix,  but you don't use [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/rand.html) or any other function for random numbers in your code. You don't use MATLAB's [`det`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/det.html) for the comparison in your code, And there are more examples...
Don't expect others to do your homework if you don't try to do it yourself

Comment: `rand` is a function, you don't call it as a string `'rand()'`. Furthermore, you want the user to enter a single value, not the random matrix. Look at the examples below, copy them, run them, **understand how to use them**, thd then rewrite your code.

Comment: This is very normal. The time that takes for a script of function to run is dependent on many factors and you can't control them all. The way for assessing the execution time is to run it many times (100+) and get the mean execution time, just like sampling any other semi-random variable.

Comment: That's what loops are for... or should i say `for`?
In the script that runs this function set some `N = 100` (or any other large number), initialize an array `t = zeros(N,1)`, add `for k = 1:N` before you call the function, turn on `tic`, and save the execution time using `t(k) = toc`. 
If you want too compare your function to MATLAB's one you should add another column to `t`, and add the other function to the loop, restart `tic` before each function runs and then assign `t(k,1) = toc` and `t(k,2) = toc` respectively after each function.
After the loop `end` display `mean(t)`.

Comment: see my response in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand the purpose of this second code, but as far as I can guess what you try to do, I can suggest this:

```
function out = thanksEBH
n = input('matrix A =');
A = rand(n);
N = 100;
t = zeros(N,1);
out = 1;
for k = 1:N
    tic
    % first procedure to measure run-time
    for i = 1:n
        out = prod(A(i,i)*A(i,end));
    end
    t(k,1) = toc;
    tic
    % second procedure to measure run-time
    for i = 1:n
        out = prod(A(i,end-1)*A(end,i));
    end
    t(k,2) = toc;
end
disp(mean(t))
end
```

This will measure execution time of the two inner `for` loops separately and will display the mean of them. Anything you put inside the inner `for` loops will be measured. Note that I also changed the start of the function (among some other things) so it could run.

*Please, if you have any other questions regarding this, ask them separately in a different question.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not a guru in matlab but I will to try to answer you:

For creating random arrays:

http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/create-arrays-of-random-numbers.html

In order to calulate the determinat in matlab you ca use the function det

[function det](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/det.html)

The easy way for get execution time in matlab is using the pair functions tic and toc

```
tic
A = rand(12000, 4400);
B = rand(12000, 4400);
toc
C = A'.*B';
toc
```

[tic and toc](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html)

You can ask the user with the input command:

http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html

```
prompt = 'What is the original value? ';
x = input(prompt)
y = x*10
```

[simply googling](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47306-determinant-of-matrices-using-the-leibniz-formula-recursively/content/determin.m) for a recursive determinant algorithm:

```
% The derminant of a matrix can be evaluated using a recursive formula such
% that: Assuming a square matrix A of order n
% det(A)=sum(a1j*Cj), for j=1,n
% where a1j represent the elements of the 1st row of the matrix A, and
% Cj is the determinant of the reduced matrix obtained removing the 1st row
% and the column j of the matrix A
function DetA=determin(A)

% This method can be applied for any nxn square matrix; 

% Check Input Argument
if isempty(A)
    error('cof:EmptyMatrix','The matrix A does not exist');
end

[r, c]=size(A);     % number of rows and columns of A
if r~=c
    error('det:NotSquareMatrix','The matrix A is not square');
end

DetA=0;

% Calculate determinant
if r==2,
%     if the matrix a 2x2 matrix, then directly calculate the determinant
%     using the common formula
    DetA=A(1,1)*A(2,2)-A(1,2)*A(2,1);
else
%     if the matrix is not 2x2 reduce its order of 1, generating a matrix
%     with r-1 rows and c-1 columns. Subsequently recall the function using
%     the reduced matrix
    temp_A=A;
    for i=1:c
        a1i=temp_A(1,i);    % save the element of the 1st row and ith column of the temporary matrix; this element will be used to calculate the determinant later on
        if a1i~=0
            temp_A(1,:)=[];     % remove the first row to create the reduced matrix
            temp_A(:,i)=[];     % remove the ith column to create the reduced matrix
            Cj=temp_A;
            DetCj=determin(Cj); % Calculate the determinant of the reduced matrix recalling the function
            DetA=DetA+((-1)^(1+i))*a1i*DetCj;
            temp_A=A;           % reset elements of temporary matrix to input elemens
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @babs If they're not what you need then you need to clarify your question

Comment: @excaza pls first edit my script so that it runs. Base on this script, a random matrix should be embedded in it instead of me inputting matrix manually whenever it prompts for a square matrix. The code has a "tic" and "toc" for the time execution.

Comment: I like the fact that you know a lot of things about matlab, the first thing that you should know about your code is reading the output errors, like the one that points that lenght, is not a matlab function, I hope @excaza writes and solves your execise for you, good luck!!

Comment: @anquegi why would I do that? It's a poorly posed and poorly researched question.

Comment: @excaza, I know, I know it was a joke, irony, I think that you will get it, sorry,

Comment: @anquegi it is not a joke, in fact I have gotten it but the problem now it that it does not display the result but only the time of execution. Not displaying the result but the script execute seems weird to me. please recheck my question for the latest code. Thanks

Comment: @excaza I have modified my script above that is now executable but not displaying the result, only the time of execution. I hope my script will be meaningful to you now. Thanks

Comment: @user2574723 (answered Oct 4 '14 at 6:13) Please your code for determinant using recursive function is not working. Do you have the working one? I was unable to comment in your post

Comment: @babs I'm glad it helped, please up vote the question and put valid answer, thanks, the it will be fine to work with you again

Comment: @anquegi please is it possible for a program when run on the same set of data to produce different time elapsed (time of execution). For instance, when I run my code on 2 by 2 matrix of [1,2;4,3] five times I have 0.000018,  0.000016,  0.000020,  0.000019 and 0.000023 seconds. Why are the time of execution different different

Comment: Yes it is  possible, matlab use a lot of resources, Different processes running in the background that you have no control over, Caching of memory has changed between runs, MATLAB JIT may have done more code optimization between runs, etc